# Change variable outside of reactive function/context

Tags: r, reactive-programming, shiny

I am looking for a way to change a variable, which has been initialized outside of the reactivity context in a shiny app.

Meaning: I have two variables which I need to set, depending on what happens in the shiny app, to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

That needs to be done from an an reactive function.

Example:

```
a <- FALSE
c <- FALSE

observeEvent(input$test, { #this triggers c to change to TRUE
    a <- FALSE
    c <- TRUE
)}
```

Some user clicks on the button with the `label` *test*

```
> c
> TRUE
```

Comment: So what is your question? Is the `c` variable not changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (you cannot update `c` inside the `observeEvent` function), you need to put your `c` variable in a reactive and change it inside the `observeEvent`:

```
variables = reactiveValues(a = FALSE, c = FALSE)

observeEvent(input$test, {
    variables$a = FALSE
    variables$c = TRUE
})
```

Then you can use `variables$c` in your code, and anything depending on `variables` will be updated if you press the button (e.g. a plot).

Comment: Ah, didnt know that you can store more than one variable in there! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change variables in a parent environment, use the `<<-` operator (see `?"<-"` for more information):

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn_change", "Change Values"),
  actionButton("btn_print","Print values")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  a <- F
  c <- F

  observeEvent(input$btn_change, {
    a <<- F
    c <<- T
  })

  observeEvent(input$btn_print, {
    cat("a =",a,"c =",c,"\n")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this example, `a` and `c` are per session global variables for shiny.

Comment: There is a viable alternative in the form of my answer, so I would avoid using `<<-` as that is rarely a good idea as it can unforseen effects.

Comment: In this context I don't see any harm in it. If the questioner doesn't plan to monitor these variables with observers then this is not an intented use of reactiveValues() in my understanding and adds extra load to the program which isn't needed.